# c# post photo on facebook without using c# sdk

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-graph-api, post, photo

please provide me a simple piece of code in c# to post photo on facebook without using the very famous facebook sdk for c#, as per my knowledge there are two methods of posting photos,

METHOD 1:

The fb documentation below shows a method to post image with the url provided,

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/526/?ref=nf

of course I tried, it does not seem to accept my image url, when I tried debugging here on facebook API explorer using the post method and entered the parameters as below,

SomeAlbumID/photos?=access_token=MyTOKEN&url=http%3a%2f%2fcutree.com%2fcutreefbapp%2fimg1.bmp&message=Family+Tree

It returns an exception saying

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "http\u00253a\u00252f\u00252fcutree.com\u00252fcutreefbapp\u00252fimg1.bmp is an internal url, but this is an external request.", 
    "type": "CurlUrlInvalidException"
  }
}
```

"internal url, but this is an external request." I am not sure what this means as I am using the same domain as registered on my fbapp, and also giving the request from the server itself.

I have read some where that fb accepts images from only a few servers, can anyone help me out.

METHOD 2:

This is a method where image data in bytes are atttached with the Post body as fb says "To publish a photo, issue a POST request with the photo file attachment as multipart/form-data."

However everyone does that using the fb sdk for c#, can anyone provide simple http post method for this issue.

I have tried streaming image data using a method below

```
public MyFacebookClass FBPost(string URI, string Parameters)
{
    System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("https://graph.facebook.com/" + URI);
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    req.Method = "POST";
    byte[] bytes = BmpToBytes_Serialization(new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\atul\\cutreefbapp\\DefaultThumb.bmp"));
    req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    System.IO.Stream os = req.GetRequestStream();
    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); 
    os.Close();
    System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
    if (resp == null) return null;
    System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
    return new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<MyFacebookClass>(sr.ReadToEnd().Trim());

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem you have is your code isn't correct. In order to post a photo to Facebook you'll need to use a multi-part form data post. I haven't used the C# SDK, but I'm sure it builds a multi-part form post internally before submitting the image.

You will have to do something similar to what is [posted here](http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/multipart-form-post-in-c). I was about to post my code that does this exactly for Facebook from my app, but it is a bit long.

Comment: Thanks Frazell I think I'm getting a hang of it, I will post my completed piece of code for others to refer. I like everything as simplified as possible.

Comment: _“In order to post a photo to Facebook you'll need to use a multi-part form data post.”_ – no, you don’t. Using the `url` parameter instead of `source`, and giving a publicly reachable picture URL as value works as well.

Comment: @CBroe Why down vote? There is no mention of the url query string parameter that I could find in Facebook's API documentation. Facebook API states multi-part form and the C# SDK uses this as well. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/

Is this Url parameter new?

Answer (score 0):

Posting photos by giving a parameter `url` definitively works. If it doesn’t for you, then you are doing something wrong.

(I just tried it with the URL of your picture on the Graph API Explorer, and it work as I expected it.)

> when I tried debugging here on facebook API explorer using the post method and entered the parameters as below,
>
> SomeAlbumID/photos?=access_token=MyTOKEN&url=http%3a%2f%2fcutree.com%2fcutreefbapp%2fimg1.bmp&message=Family+Tree

If that’s the *actual* address you tried to post to, then the `=` between `photos?` and `access_token` is clearly wrong.